# lstlisting on the same page with Chapter title?

Tags: listings

I am trying to put my lstlisting on the same page as the Chapter title. Since the chapter is in my appendix I do not have any other content exept the lstlisting. Currently, the lstlisting is going on the next page and the page with the chapter is empty. Is there a solution to this?

This is my code:

```
\chapter{ARFF dataset file sample}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=WEKA ARFF file extract,
label=weka-arff-code,
captionpos=b,
frame=single,
basicstyle=\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont,
float,
floatplacement=H,
breaklines=true]
@relation HAR

@attribute accX__fft1 numeric
@attribute accX__fft2 numeric
@attribute accX__fft3 numeric
@attribute accX__fft4 numeric
@attribute accX__fft5 numeric
@attribute accY__fft1 numeric
@attribute accY__fft2 numeric
@attribute accY__fft3 numeric
@attribute accY__fft4 numeric
@attribute accY__fft5 numeric
@attribute accZ__fft1 numeric
@attribute accZ__fft2 numeric
@attribute accZ__fft3 numeric
@attribute accZ__fft4 numeric
@attribute accZ__fft5 numeric
@attribute accM__fft1 numeric
@attribute accM__fft2 numeric
@attribute accM__fft3 numeric
@attribute accM__fft4 numeric
@attribute accM__fft5 numeric
@attribute class {walking,running,static,cycling}

@data
9,-76,-834,25,22,4,-1,-401,-190,-3,3,5,-213,-94,-45,2,-50,-49,-15,18,walking
-0,-184,140,4,-34,-2,13,45,63,-8,0,51,-68,-30,-72,1,-52,15,-51,63,walking
-1,-13,-30,3,2,3,-18,-2,3,-21,-1,2,-4,-9,-1,-2,33,3,16,20,walking
0,-16,-17,-22,6,-3,-6,-8,-16,-3,-15,-2,12,-5,9,8,8,37,38,-18,walking
-6,-22,14,-54,1,14,8,27,9,60,-22,-31,-11,-11,4,-7,1,0,-3,-39,running
-3,-11,-35,-3,-53,-13,-45,23,-57,17,-2,52,13,58,15,22,48,-36,25,-50,running
3,7,-11,27,-41,-19,-31,-53,-107,10,0,-42,22,-42,3,20,34,-26,76,-104,running
-3,37,34,9,58,0,30,97,-74,83,4,-13,-39,40,26,-4,15,-10,27,-26,cycling
-1,-91,-131,-121,-58,-4,6,-66,22,70,3,-30,-76,-63,-30,-1,-39,-10,-39,-76,cycling
1,-54,-41,-180,114,-3,4,-21,78,-188,3,8,-56,-19,70,0,-38,22,-83,103,cycling
0.3,0,-1,1,-1.4,0,1,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,static
0,-6,48,-8,0,0,-6,-21,2,5,0,-1,42,-6,0,0,0,-1.5,0,-1.6,static
-0.3,8,-4,3,-4,0.1,6,-4,2,-3,0,2,-2,2,-1,0,0.2,1,-0.4,0.2,static
\end{lstlisting}
```

and the result:
[image]

Comment: Does removing the `float` statement in the `lstlisting` options help?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It was that simple! Thank you so much! If you want you can put your comment in an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `float` and `floatplacement` options have been used in the `lstlisting` environment, the listing is caused to float away to a position where `LaTeX` thinks it would be placed best, especially if the size of the float is too large to fit on a chapter opening page.

Just remove the `float` specification, i.e. the listing will start right at the position it is specified in the document (if there's enough space)